# kubectl: Connection to server was refused

Tags: docker, containers, yaml, kubernetes, kubectl

When I run `kubectl run` ... or any command I get an error message saying

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

What exactly is this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really don't know much about kubectl... But the various reasons you have a connection refused to localhost I know of are as follows

- 1) Make sure you can resolve and ping your local host with the IP(127.XX.XX.XX) and also "localhost" if using a DNS or host file.
- 2) Make sure the service trying to access the localhost has enough permissions to run as root if trying to use localhost.
- 3) Check the ports with netstat and check for the appropriate flags you need amongst the "Plantu" flags, Look up the meaning of each of the flags as it would apply to your situation. If the service you are trying to access on localhost is listening on that port, netstat would let you know.
- 4) Check if you have admin or management settings in your application that needs permissions to access your localhost in the configuration parameters of your application.
- 5) According to the statement that says did you specify the right host or port, this means that either your "kubectl" run is not configured to run as localhost instead your primary DNS server hostname or IP, Check what host is configured to run your application and like I said check for the appropriate ports to use, You can use telnet to check this port and further troubleshoot form there.

My two cents!

Comment: Point 5 helps - configure your kubectl to make it work locally with dockers

Comment: Use `nc -vz 127.0.0.1 <port>` to ping a concrete port

Answer (score 29):

In my case, working with minikube I had not started minikube. Starting minikube with

```
minikube start
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases, this means a missing kubeconfig file. kubectl is trying to use the default values when there is no $HOME/.kube/config.
You must create or copy a valid `config` file to solve this problem.
For example if you are using kubeadm you can solve this with:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Alternatively you can also export KUBECONFIG variable like this:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have just installed k3s on my laptop along with kubectl and docker. I do not have the kubeconfig file in /etc/* too. What could be the solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: k3s stores the cluster kubeconfig by default in: `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`. I do recommend reading this doc as well: https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/cluster-access/

Answer (score 5):

creating cluster before running kubectl worked for me

> gcloud container clusters create k0

Comment: What about restarting it ? As this problem will happen if you restart your computer; kubectl won't know where to connect

Comment: or just "selecting" the cluster again, after creating it:
```gcloud container clusters get-credentials k0```

Comment: @AAAton yeah, agree

Comment: @Ben you can use the get-credentials command in case of a restart and sorry for the delay in response

Answer (score 4):

If swap is not disabled, **kubelet** service will not start on the masters and nodes, for **Platform9** Managed `Kubernetes version 3.3 and above`..

By running the below command to turn off swap memory

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

To make it permanent 
go to `/etc/fstab` and comment the swap line
works well..

Comment: In my case this was exactly the issue, so thank you for the hint! Apparently something or someone turned on the swap again (because the cluster was working just fine before).

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie in k8s, came here while working with microk8s &
want to use kubectl (cli command) on microk8s cluster.

run below command (this generates config file, which is used by `kubectl`)

```
microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
```

got the solution from this link, https://microk8s.io/docs/working-with-kubectl

**Good to know**

- kubectl needs a config file(commonly called as `kubeconfig` file) to work with cluster (here microk8s cluster)
- kubeconfig file consists of cluster/server name, default context, user details, etc (means it may contain sensitive info)

Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue when I executed `kubectl get pods`. The reason was docker desktop was not running, then I ran the docker desktop, checked for the docker and k8s running . Then again I ran `kubectl get pods`
same output. Then I started minikube by `minikube start`. Everything went normal.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same issue when I executed kubectl command. The are various reasons you have a connection refused to your host. Some of those reason are follow:

1. Make sure you properly configure your kube config file (~/.kube/config). you can check using the following command `kubectl config view` the output should be like this

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://<<your host>>:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
    client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED
```

if not you can follow this official process to update it

```
  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Alternatively, if you are the root user, you can run:

```
  export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

2. Update your Container Runtime Interface (CRI) Cgroup Driver
   this scenario can often be identify by the instability of kubelet the `systemctl status kubelet`

   a. Case you are using containerd as cri follow theses command

   - open `vi /etc/containerd/config.toml`
   - change this `SystemdCgroup = false` to `SystemdCgroup = true`
   - `sudo systemctl restart containerd`
   - `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
   - reboot your machine (may be optional)

   b. Case you are using docker as cri follow theses command

   - open `vi /etc/docker/daemon.json`
   - change this `["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]` to `"exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"],`
   - `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
   - `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
   - reboot your machine (may be optional)

I hope this summary help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are configuring with eksctl and kubectl you can use the following command

**eksctl utils write-kubeconfig --cluster yourclustername --region your-region**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try run with `sudo` permission mode
 `sudo kubectl run....`